# Min and Max Values are incorrect

Tags: c

I'm still a greenhorn when it comes to programming. To put it simply, I had to run my code through different sets of data. For all negative numbers, my max is incorrect. For all positive numbers, my minimum is incorrect. I am aware that it is because they were initially set to 1 since the item was set to 1 but I do not know how to remedy this. This is all in C btw.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define       BUFSIZE       1024

int main()
{
    int itemsread;
    double item = 1;
    //initial value so loop starts
        int howmany = 0;
    //the count
        double max = item;
    double min = item;
    char line[BUFSIZE];
    double mean;
    double sum;

    while (item != 0 && fgets(line, BUFSIZE, stdin) != NULL) {
        itemsread = sscanf(line, "%lf", &item);
        if (itemsread == 1 && item != 0) {
            howmany++;
            sum += item;
            mean = sum / howmany;

            if (item > max) {
                max = item;
            }
            if (item < min) {
                min = item;
            }
        } else {
            printf("bad input\n");
        }

    }
    printf("# items: %d\n", howmany);

    if (howmany != 0) {
        printf("sum: %f\n", sum);
        printf("Maximum: %f\n", max);
        printf("Minimum: %f\n", min);
        printf("Mean: %f\n", mean);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indentation would be very helpful.

Comment: second min check should be `min = item;` not max.

Comment: I forgot I had already changed it and it still gives me my problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your min check is off:

```
if (item < min) {
    max = item;
}
```

change to

```
if (item < min) {
    min = item;
}
```

You should also assign your min and max to the first entry you receive from your input.  Otherwise, your min will never set unless the value is < 1 and your max will never set unless > 1.

You can use your `howmany` value to check this.  If it is 0 before the first increment, set min and max to `item` at that point.

Also, since your `sum` is a running value, you need to assign it to `0`

```
double sum = 0;
```

In general, not initializing values on creation will cause "fun" later in code.  Basically, get in the habit of initializing all your variables to values on creation.  See RAII - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization

Comment: `sum` needs to be initialized as well.

Comment: Did you fix the `howmany` part I suggested?  I dont' want to just give you the single if statement and assignments as you won't get as much.  But that is the next part you need to consider.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I fixed the min/max part! But thank you for the howmany part!! That saved me!